# Adobe Illustrator - Copy gradient of one object into another object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, hotkeys

Does anybody know the keyboard shortcut or the easiest way to copy a gradient of an object into another object.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Select the object you want to apply the gradient to, hit `i` to bring up the eyedropper, and click on the object whose gradient you want to apply.

Answer (score 9):

To maintain the angle of any gradient, drag the object containing the gradient to the Graphic Styles Panel.

Then click the new object you want the gradient to be applied to and click the style in the Graphic Styles panel.

The eyedropper will pick up colors for the gradient, but it does *not* pick up location and angle of the gradient.

Comment: Sorry not working, the gradient direction is not saved in the style